# How to remove data from a calculation with a specific identifier and put it back after the calculation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-manipulation

I am a newbie to python but find that i really like how pandas works. I have two identifiers in a column: C, NC. stands for Core and NonCore. I want to get the mean of the core only. The below will remove the NC, but it keeps it out of the final dataframe.
Full Test Code below:

```
    import pandas
    import numpy as np
    usecols = ['Arcade','Assetnum','Core Or Noncore','Theo Win Per Day Amt']
    
    df = pd.read_csv('test_data.csv',index_col=False, sep=',', thousands=',',na_values=['N/A'])[usecols]
    
    df = df.applymap(lambda x: x.strip() if isinstance(x, str) else x)
    df.fillna(0, inplace=True)
    df.replace(np.nan, 0, inplace=True)
    
    df['Theo Win Per Day Amt'] = df['Theo Win Per Day Amt'].round(2)
    df.insert(4, 'ARC_TWPD_AVG', 0)

    new_names = {'Assetnum':'Asset','Theo Win Per Day Amt':'TWPD',}

    df.rename(columns=new_names, inplace=True)
    arcades = df['Arcade'].drop_duplicates()
    
    for a in arcades:
    
        ARC_TWPD_AVG = df[df['Arcade'] == a]['TWPD'].mean()
        
        df.loc[df['Arcade'] == a,'ARC_TWPD_AVG'] = (df.loc[df['Arcade'] == a,'TWPD']).mean()

    writer = pd.ExcelWriter('test_data.xlsx')
    df.to_excel(writer, index = False)
    
    writer.save()
```

I dont know how to attach a json file to this.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to filter the dataframe and then take the mean:

```
df[df['C/NC'] == 'C']['COLUMN'].mean()
```